# Null Reference Exception Error - Unity,C#

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am getting "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object", I dont know what is wrong in my code:

I have a class "EnemyInfo" as

```
public class EnemyInfo  {   
public GameObject enemyObject;  
}
```

In another class "Enemies" I am using it like this:

```
public class Enemies :  MonoBehaviour  {    

public static List<GameObject> gos;
public static List<EnemyInfo> gosN = new List<EnemyInfo>();

void FixedUpdate() {
gos = new List<GameObject>(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemy"));
gosN.Add(null)
gosN[0].enemyObject = gos[0].gameObject   //here I am getting error, dont know y :S

}
}
```

Comment: You just added a `null` value to the list, then tried to access a property of it in the next line.  Of course, it's going to throw a NullReferenceException when you do that.

Answer (score 5):

Thats because `gos` contains only one object which is *null*.

that's why you're getting a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: edit: I am first trying to initialize gosN.Add(null) and then accessing gosN[0], what should i add instead of null then something like gosN.Add(new EnemyInfo....)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect `gos[0].gameObject` is the issue.

If `gos` is empty to begin with, doing `gos.Add(null)`, adds a `null` entry.

You then access this value with `gos[0]` and try to invoke a member on it - since this is a `null`, you are getting a `NullReferenceException`.

Don't add a `null` `GameObject`.

Answer (score 1):

The list is empty, you don't have an instance to refer to public instance members

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, after

```
gos.Add(null)
```

you have `gos[0] == null`. So `gos[0].gameObject` dereferences `null`-reference.